# Django Search Query comparing votes and post age with Annotate

Tags: mysql, django, search, filter, annotate

I trying to make a django query to get posts order by **VOTES** - **POST AGE**.

**Example:**

Normal Posts

```
1 - Hello World (10 votes) (Posted today)
2 - Stackoverflow ( 12 votes) (Posted 2 days ago)
3 - StackExchange ( 30 votes ) (Posted 19 days ago)
```

So when I filter query by annotate, I want this:

```
1 - StackExchange ( 30 votes - 19 days ago = 11 points)
2 - Hello World ( 10 votes - 0 days ago = 10 points)
3 - Stackoverflow ( 12 votes - 2 days ago = 10 points)
```

I try:

```
class DiffDays(Func):
    function = 'DATEDIFF'
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s)"


class CastDate(Func):
    function = 'DATE_FORMAT'
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s, '%%%%Y-%%%%m-%%%%d')"


list_posts = posts.extra(
    select={'pub_date': "DATE_FORMAT(pub_date,'%%%%Y-%%%%m-%%%%d')"}
).annotate(
    diff_days=DiffDays(
        CastDate(today), F('pub_date')), output_field = DecimalField()
).annotate(
    days_votes=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('n_votes') - F('diff_days'), output_field=IntegerField())
).order_by('days_votes')
```

but I'm getting: `'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'`

Answer (score 1):

now `output_field` in annotate for `diff_days` is an argument of the annotate, but it have to be  an argument of `DiffDays`, so your need add brackets for put it inside func `DiffDays`

```
today = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

annotate(
    diff_days=DiffDays(
        (today, F('pub_date')), output_field=DecimalField())
      #^^^                                                ^^^
)
```

Comment: I getting this: `sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

Comment: how did you get `today`?

Comment: `today = datetime.date.today()`

Comment: can you try updated version, i don't use mysql, are you sure in the date format `'%%%%Y-%%%%m-%%%%d'`? by  [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) it looks like `'%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: Will not work. `'%%%%Y-%%%%m-%%%%d'` equals `'%Y-%m-%d'`. But if I just use `'%Y-%m-%d'`, Python think I using string format like `%s`.

Comment: Same thing: `sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154391/discussion-between-bear-brown-and-guilherme-ia).